# What is the correct way to use the javascript .onclick function?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

When using .onclick to run a function, it isn't executing it. Have I done something wrong?

```
<script>
  const object1 = document.getElementById('object1');
  const image2Path = "image2.svg";

  object1.onclick = () => {
    object1.src = image2Path;
  }
</script>
<body>
  <img id='object1' src="image1.svg">
</body>
```

I'm expecting image1 (which shows up successfully) to change to image2 when I click on the object.

Comment: You're missing a `}`. Always check your browser console for errors before asking why things aren't working.

Comment: Your script runs before your browser even sees the `object1`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, sorry, that was a typo. That is not an issue in the actual file.

Comment: @tkausl, so I should just run the script at the end of the html document?

Comment: Either this or put the whole script in an onload handler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the onclick handler correctly. This would be a way to do it:

```
<script>
  function toogle()
  {
     const object1 = document.getElementById('object1');
     const image2Path = "image2.svg";

     object1.src = image2Path;
  }
</script>
<body>
  <img id='object1' src="image1.svg" onclick="toggle();">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const object1 = document.getElementById('object1');
  const image2Path = "image2.svg";

  object1.onclick = () => {
    object1.src = image2Path;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <img id='object1' src="image1.svg">
</body>
```